# npm install / discordjs err

Tags: javascript, npm

npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\SSEUNG\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\windows-build-tools
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node ./dist/index.js
Downloading python-2.7.15.amd64.msi
npm ERR! [============================================>] 100.0% of 20.25 MB (11.57 MB/s)
npm ERR! Downloaded python-2.7.15.amd64.msi. Saved to C:\Users\SSEUNG.windows-build-tools\python-2.7.15.amd64.msi.
Downloading BuildTools_Full.exe
npm ERR! [============================================>] 100.0% of 3.29 MB (3.29 MB/s)
npm ERR! Downloaded BuildTools_Full.exe. Saved to C:\Users\SSEUNG.windows-build-tools\BuildTools_Full.exe.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Starting installation...
npm ERR! Please restart this script from an administrative PowerShell!
npm ERR! The build tools cannot be installed without administrative rights.
npm ERR! To fix, right-click on PowerShell and run "as Administrator".

### npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\SSEUNG\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2021-10-28T09_36_15_947Z-debug.log

How can I fix these errors?

Comment: You should read the error message. `Please restart this script from an administrative PowerShell! npm ERR! The build tools cannot be installed without administrative rights. npm ERR! To fix, right-click on PowerShell and run "as Administrator".`

Comment: Do I need to run the powershell terminal as administrator in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: Also is it related to the error with Node.js v17.0.1?

Comment: You have to open the PowerShell as administrator. If you want to use it in VSCode, you have to open the PowerShell as administrator in VSCode.

Comment: After running Visual Studio Code as administrator, I typed npm install in the powershell terminal but got the same error again  error Screenshot -> https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/893148743942144100/903224787395018782/SharedScreenshot.jpg

Comment: Do you really think that `Can't find module` and `Please restart this script from an administrative PowerShell!` is the same error? Again: Please read the error messages.

Comment: This seems to be a node version issue. I reinstalled node to version 16 and the error was resolved normally.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom of the error message it says to fix this, right click on the PowerShell and run it as the administrator. Click on the search bar in the taskbar and type in windows PowerShell, right click the search result and click run as administrator.